# boolean postfix notation

Tags: c++, c, math, abstract-data-type

I have to write an ADT character stack to handle postfix notation for boolean values.

This is an example of one of the postfix notations.

T T && F || ! ( this will be the input text)

I know that this evaluates to false.

My question is.

What does this notation end up looking like in code.
(once the input string has been parsed)

My guess is:

```
if ( !( true && true || false) )
    //do something;
else
    //do something else
```

I'm fairly sure this is wrong and I am way off the mark,
I have tried all sorts of combinations.
I can't get it to return false.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure about the logical order of the if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually interpret RPN stack-wise, with binary operators popping two arguments off the stack, and unary one.

1. `T T` — pushes two *true* values onto the stack, stack is: `T T`,
2. `&&` — pops two values, pushes *and*: `T && T`, stack is: `T`,
3. `F` — pushes *false* onto the stack, stack is: `T F`,
4. `||` — pops two values, pushes *or*: `T || F`, stack is: `T`,
5. `!` — pops one value, pushes negated version: `!T`, stack is: `F`.

So your final result is the result of these operations (written from bottom to top):

```
bool result = !(false || (true && true));
```

---

You just need to read it from the end; it might be a bit easier when converted to prefix notation first (from bottom to top):

```
! ( || ( F && ( T T ) ) )
```

Then you an just move the binary operators inside the parentheses:

```
! ( || ( F && ( T    T ) ) )
     -----> ----->
! (      F || ( T && T ) )
```

Comment: great, that looks like what I need, thanks. very clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem shoud be because you're returning the opposite from what the `if` condition evaluates to (see ablm comment). But in general you should wrap every evaluated expression in parenthesis to ensure a correct result:

```
return !((true && true) || false);
```

This way, even if the precedence of the operators in your target language (C/C++) is different from the intended order of computation, the expression will still be evaluated how you want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !( true && true || false) ) <-- this is false
    return false; <-- this evaluates if expression inside if is true, which is not
else
    return true; <--- if expression inside if is false then this(true) is returned.
```

So for proper return type you will need to interchange returns.

```
if ( !( true && true || false) )
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: Ah! so is the if statement correct? based on your comment it appears I am correct?

Comment: @derek Yes, the if statement is correct. According to [this table of operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), `&&` binds stronger than `||`, so `true && true || false` is the same as `(true && true) || false`. If this were not the case, the absence of the parenthesis could be troublesome and produce an incorrect result.